# Rest API call during the application startup in spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have a requirement to call the rest API call to other application to get the properties and these properties can be used application level.

This is needed to be during the application startup and ready for use by the entire application.
For example, we have PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer which can be included in the application-context. But we don't want to include the properties here.

Is there any other class which will initialize the application during the context startup?

Thanks, 
Kk

Answer (score 1):

You can create an ApplicationListener. This approach can be used for running logic after the Spring context has been initialized.

In order to achieve this you need to create a bean that implements the ApplicationListener interface:

```
@Component
public class StartupApplicationListenerExample implements
ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent> {

 private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(StartupApplicationListenerExample.class);

 public static int counter;

 @Override public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
    LOG.info("Increment counter");
    counter++;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CommandLineRunner

example

```
@Component
public class MyBean implements CommandLineRunner {
public void run(String... args) {
    // Do something...
}
}
```

And then use a RestTemplate to invoke
`RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();`

Answer (score 0):

Annotate a method with `@PostConstruct` annotation and put the logic to call your REST Api in it.

Answer (score 0):

If you receive only your properties from this third-application, you probably should take a look at Spring Cloud Config (https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/).

With this project you can set up an application, which provides only properties to everyone who is asking. The properties can be stored on git or whatever you like.

Having this as a properties-provider running, you can retrieve your properties from there and merge those with your local ones. 
This is all done at app-startup.